# MacOS Mojave | PyCharm Is not allowed to access to the camera

Tags: macos, terminal, camera, pycharm, opencv

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

print('Camera initialized')

ret, raw_frame = video_capture.read()

video_capture.release()

print('Bye!')
```

When I execute it from the native MacOS terminal, it is able to complete its execution. The problem came when I tried to do it from PyCharm. The first time I executed it from the native terminal I got a popup message asking me for permissions to let the terminal use the camera, and it worked. However, when I do the same from PyCharm I don't get this message so the camera fails to initialize with the following error message:

> ```
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
> ```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230407/process-finished-with-exit-code-134-interrupted-by-signal-6-sigabrt-in-python) and they seemed to have the same problem, but when I modified my file as explained I wasn't able to get it working.

Comment: I am not totally clear about your question.  Have you tried launching PyCharm from the terminal?

Comment: Executing the code above from Pycharm doesn't work and I have the error message showed above. But when I do it from the terminal "python xx_file.py" it works properly. Seems like Pycharm is not able to ask for permission to the operating system to use the camera.

Comment: What I am implying is that by launching PyCharm itself from the command line, you might see the very popup that you aren't seeing otherwise.  This is nothing more than something to try.  I am assuming that you ALREADY tried going into System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Camera and looked for PyCharm in there.

Comment: I found one possibility.. can you edit PyCharms info.plist file?  [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios).  It is probably the same thing for MacOs.. hacking this is what any Linux user would try to do ;^)  Perhaps it will send you down the right path.

Comment: That's a known PyCharm issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219288

Comment: Yes, seems like it is a known issue. Hope PyCharm will soon release the fix for it. I tried to edit the Info.plist but it didn't work for me...

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404700/unable-to-read-video-in-macbook-pro-catalina-os-using-opencv-4-1-1-videocapture/58997222#58997222